# How do I cure Orb Piercer poison?

Tags: made-in-abyss-binary-star

I got poisoned by an Orb Piercer on the 4th Layer of the Abyss. The poison effect is purple and drains both my health and hunger. The Red, Blue, and Paralysis antidotes don't have any effect. How do I cure Orb Piercer poison?

[image: Dying from purple orb piercer poison]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is meet Nanachi, who you can find by:

> Killing yourself with fall damage.

([Source and tips here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1324340/discussions/0/3473986888164380460/))

Then, you should be able to acquire the [Orb Piercer Venom.](https://madeinabyss.fandom.com/wiki/Nanachi#cite_note-Ch021Pg7-8-87)
[image]

Comment: It seems the poison also gets cured if you return to the surface or give up your current run.